# Assembler Language Programming for IBM and IBM Compatible Computers

Tags: assembly

I just started taking an Assembly Language course in College. 
We are using the textbook listed in my title. (Nancy Stern, Alden Sager, Robert A. Stern)
We are using the PC-370 IBM Mainframe Emulator.
Presently we are using Notepad++ to write the MLC files.
What I am looking for is a better text editor or IDE that is intended for writing Assembly Language... and that will work with the PC-370 Emulator.
Notepad++ does not tab to correct positions, etc...

I have spent a lot of time and effort trying to find something that would fit my needs, but am not sure if any of them would be compatible for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to look at Emacs or VIM?

Also, here are a couple of links which might give you something you want:

- [List of various obscure text editors](http://texteditors.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?EditorIndex)
- [List of modes for Emacs, one of which might be what you need](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProgrammingModes)
- [Assembly-related question about VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782384/assembly-vim-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

I use another scintilla based editor geany.  Not difficult at all to re-purpose one of the or the assembly language backend to whatever keywords, tabs, etc.  I think a lot of that is the scintilla engine not geany so notepad++ likely also provides that ability.